# HP Z600 Workstation max memory figures

Tags: memory-limit, workstation

I have this workstation with the C2 revision motherboard. HP sources say that this will support 48GB memory (6x 8GB) but I keep seeing people touting 96GB (6x 16GB) all over the place.
Does anyone actually have any experience of this working and if so, is it as simple as buying six 16GB DIMMs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe there is a bios update that supports 96gb.

Answer (score 0):

Googlin' away, it seems that someone else has tried something like that, successfully.

You may have a look at [this post](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Business-PCs-Workstations-and-Point-of-Sale-Systems/Out-of-spec-Z600/td-p/7027523) from some HP local site, where you may find detailed Cpu-Z memory specs, in case you want to take the plunge.

Hope it helps, good luck and kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I can personally say that 96GB works, if you have ECC Registered memory.
Currently running Dual X5650 with 6x 16GB DIMM without issue.
I have the V2 Z600 btw